# Navbar not appears responsive mode bootstrap 3 + joomla

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla, nav

Dears I am working on www site. In normal desktop mode everything works fine but when I am changing it to responsive mode menu dissapears.

Case is connected with module breadcrumbs. When I turn the module off it works perfectly.

Looking for help.

Here is my code:

Navbar section:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
        Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->

        <!-- Jumbotron -->   
        <div class="jumbotron">

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slider" style="xhtml" /> 

        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-justified">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav2" style="xhtml" /> 
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*may be you have already button included but try to locate button by apply css like following: to '.navbar-toggle' class*

```
.navbar-toggle { background-color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actually your navbar-button color may be inherit css of your site so if you assign custom css like below you can see button like standard button.

.navbar-toggle {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.navbar-toggle span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Please can you merge this answer with your previous one, rather than posting multiple answer